# How to print file path with directory Indentation Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Printing file path with directory indentation.
Input will be

```
[
  "/root/html/file/a.html",
  "/root/html/image/a.jpg",
  "/root/html/file/b.html",
  "/tmp/c.log"
]
```

Output needs to be like following,

```
- root
  - html 
     - file
       - a.html
       - b.html
     - image
       - a.jpg
- tmp
  - c.log
```

I couldn't find any solution. I guess it will be a recursive call with a tree structure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What code have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: IDK what your trying to do, but it sounds a lot like printing a tree.

Comment: You can check this module out. This might do what you want: https://www.npmjs.com/package/print-tree

Comment: You should include some debugging info, or offer something you have tried. Right now it kinda looks like your asking people to write code for you. No one wants to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could map each file path of your input data into a simple tree-map structure and then recursively print this structure. Something like this (not tested and might still need to handle edge cases):

```js
function processData(data) {
    const separator = "/";
    const tree = {};
    data.forEach(element => mapPathToTree(tree, element.split(separator).filter(part => part)));
    printTree(tree, 0);
}

function mapPathToTree(tree, pathParts) {
    if (pathParts && pathParts.length <= 1) {
        tree[pathParts[0]] = {};
        return;
    }
    const currPart = pathParts[0];
    let subTree = tree[currPart];
    if (!subTree) {
        subTree = {};
        tree[currPart] = subTree;
    }
    mapPathToTree(subTree, pathParts.slice(1));
}

function printTree(subTree, level) {
    for (const key in subTree) {
        console.log(" ".repeat(level).concat("- ").concat(key));
        printTree(subTree[key], level + 1);
    }
}

processData([
    "/root/html/file/a.html",
    "/root/html/image/a.jpg",
    "/root/html/file/b.html",
    "/tmp/c.log"
]);
```

Comment: @MSMOHAN: any feedback?